# API to create objects for approval.

Tags: api, approval-process

I would like a form on our website that people can fill out and indicate which of our products they are interested in. Can I create a form that will then create contacts and Opportunities in Salesforce that will require approval before they are counted in any of our statistics? Will this use the API in some way?

I currently use some web to lead forms and have created flows that process the information to where it is needed, but our product offerings is getting to the point where this isn't feasible for leads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage the process builder functionality which can provide you an solution to

1. Create a new Account, Contact record
2. Submit record for approval as shown below.

while creating new lead from web

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can use the API to create the records and then create a process that will submit them for approval. That seems simple enough.